# Deployed (to) shinyapp.io looks different than local version and does not run?

Tags: r, shiny

We have a shiny app that was developed on local machine and deployed to shinyapps.io

The deployed version loads most of the way but 'greys out' after a few seconds, and the function which is used to pull data in (on the far left of our app) does not load, so data can not be called in to the app.

screen shots:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwjRDz3PpMerS3RXbkhQT3R1cHc/view?usp=sharing

Any ideas why this may occur?

No code is changed and all files seemed to deploy to shinyapps.io

Comment: Without code it is difficult to know - but my first guess is that there is a path to a file that works in your code locally but does not work when moved to shinyapps.

Comment: Check the log file in the shinyapps admin console. In case you developed on Windows, note that Shinyapps is Linux and therefore file names are case sensitive.

Comment: I assume you create those boxes with `htmlOutput()` or `uiOutput()`. This only means that their render counterpart in the server doesn't run.

Comment: Thank you  - the log files did show that this was a capitalization issue with one of the .R files.  Did not know the log files were there - a link to the log with the error message would have been good for us newbies!  Thanks to all for the help.